# What is holding SLS back from launching?

Tags: rockets, nasa, sls

I'm kind of confused on this point SLS has engines, a [tank](https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/multimedia/welding-complete-on-fuel-tank-for-sls-rocket/), side rocket boosters, a capsule, and seemingly all of the pieces. What is the major technical issue right now that is keeping SLS from launching?

Comment: Projects like this go through repeated cycles of test and review every time two subcomponents are joined.

Comment: Launching to.... where?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The [EM-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploration_Mission-1) mission, presumably.

Comment: @RussellBorogove thank you, I probably should've worded that without the ellipses, it was a literal question.

Comment: there's a premise here that a "major technical issue" exists. That a government contractor is slow to deliver doesn't mean that the issue is necessarily technical in nature.

Comment: There's a nice summary in Axios: [NASA's moonshot whiplash](https://www.axios.com/nasa-whiplash-five-year-moonshot-adafe604-a5da-4455-a196-ab7d25021d5f.html) though there's nothing specific to answer your question.

Comment: AFAIK no complete vehicle has been assembled, and therefore no integrated testing has been done.